# Right border of the AddThis counter missing with Twitter's Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, addthis, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using the default code from http://www.addthis.com/ with Twitter's Bootstrap 3 the right border of the counter is missing:

[image: Addthis buttons and counter with Twitter's Bootstrap 3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter's Bootstrap 3 use a CSS's universal selector to set box-sizing (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to border-box. This will be save cause support for IE7 has been dropped. This selector breaks the AddThis counter.

The counter is set by: `<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>`.

**Solution**:
Reset the box-sizing for the .addthis_counter class. Add the following code after your bootstrap css:

```
 .addthis_counter
{
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Or Less:

```
.addthis_counter,
.addthis_counter * { .box-sizing(content-box); }
```

See also: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties and [Why did Bootstrap 3 switch to box-sizing: border-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box/18858771#18858771)