# Twitter's Bootstrap 3 with ShareThis widget

Tags: sharethis, twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap3 looks like there is a compatibility issue with the sharethis app widgets... images looked cropped due to the use of

{ -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
see demo
http://gurroladesign.com/bootstrap3/

compatibily issue not existant on previous version of bootstrap
http://gurroladesign.com/bootstrap/starter-template.html

have not been able to solve? any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap your code (span tags) in a container and reset css box-sizing property to `content-box` of this spans (see also: [Right border of the AddThis counter missing with Twitter's Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128730/right-border-of-the-addthis-counter-missing-with-twitters-bootstrap-3)):

**your html**:

```
<div id="sharethis">    
  <span class='st_sharethis_hcount' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
  <span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
  <span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
  <span class='st_linkedin_hcount' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
  <span class='st_pinterest_hcount' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
  <span class='st_email_hcount' displayText='Email'></span>
</div>
```

**css** (add after the Bootstrap CSS):

```
#sharethis span
{
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: share this changes there widget... you cant add html via the widget ui in wordpress, gonna have to modiy the core files... or simple fix it might work  'code'  p span { -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      box-sizing: content-box;}

Comment: to modify core files...  share-this/sharethis.php... return $content.'<p class="test">'.st_makeEntries().'</p>';

Comment: This solution doesn't work for "Sharing buttons with vertical counters" because the bubble remains unaffected. You have to use a wider selector like `#sharethis *`. It's not elegant bu it worked for me.