# Bootstrap components with alternate colors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

Is there a recommended way to have 2 Bootstrap components with different color sets?

For example, two nav-tabs, one in a dark theme, and another in a light theme.

Preferably something like:

```
<div class="dark"><ul class="nav nav-tabs"> ... </ul></div>
<header>...</header>
<div class="light"><ul class="nav nav-tabs"> ... </ul></div>
```

But something like this might be fine:

```
<ul class="dark-nav dark-nav-tabs"> ... </ul>
<header>...</header>
<ul class="dark-nav light-nav-tabs"> ... </ul>
```

I would rather include 2 Bootstrap CSS files, one with dark variables.less and one with light colors, but have the styles prefixed in some kind of namespace. Ideally I would want to minimize the risk of accidentally typing  or something. Having a  around the dark areas would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

In LESS, you can import other `.less`/`.css` files [wherever you want](http://lesscss.org/#-importing), also inside rulesets:

```
#dark {
   @import "style-dark.less";
}

#light {
   @import "style-light.less";
}
```

Combining this with Bootstrap options that let you [customize colors](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables), you should be able to achieve the desired results, simply importing two generated files into appriopriate rulesets.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I @import "bootstrap.less" under a class like this, it fails to compile the less. Nested mixins are not resolved properly.

Comment: Try using CSS file - I think `bootstrap.min.css` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange for me to `@import "bootstrap.less" under a class` cause bootstrap.less contains the import for every file of Booststrap's css. See also: [Is it possible to apply bootstrap for a div only, using CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343043/is-it-possible-to-apply-bootstrap-for-a-div-only-using-cdn/1934577)

Try to take a look how Bootstrap do this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10332

> The thinking behind this is that the pure .navbar class only provides layout styles etc, and >all colors are applied by the modifier classes.

For example a button has two classes always `.btn` for layout styles and .`btn-*` b.e. `btn-error` for colors. I think you could use the same strategy.

You should use something like:

`<ul class="nav nav-dark nav-tabs nav-tab-dark"> ... </ul>`

Where you define in for example custom-nav.less (imported in bootstrap.less):

```
.nav-tabs-dark > li.active > a, 
.nav-tabs-dark > li.active > a:hover, 
.nav-tabs-dark > li.active > a:focus
{
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
}
```

etc.