# jQuery Chosen not rendering correctly with Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I am seeing an issue with jQuery Chosen plugin when used with Bootstrap 3, at least when there is more than one select atop another. The height of the select (multiple) is about half the size required, and the text is cut off (and therefore unreadable).

Does anyone know why this might be, or if there are any good examples of chosen being used with Bootstrap 3 (like select2 provides).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chosen.js styling not conforming to Bootstrap3 styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355026/chosen-js-styling-not-conforming-to-bootstrap3-styles)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was editing the bootstrap.css file, and commenting out

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

This was the css styling that was breaking mine.  I am not sure where it is require in bootstrap but it fixed the issue for me and the styling still looked correct to me.