# twitter bootstrap box-sizing ruined my layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

my layout broken when I implement bootstrap during the half way of my project, fixed that with some css modification, and I had commented out this

```
/**,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}*/
```

in bootstrap.css, will that affect its core? I just want to use the grid system in my project..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, don't do that. Removing the `box-sizing: border-box` will ruin your grid. See also: [Why did Bootstrap 3 switch to box-sizing: border-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box/18858771)

An example to show what happens:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:lightblue;"> 
    <div class="row" style="background-color:red;"> 
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange"><p style="background-color:green">Content</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange"><p style="background-color:green">Content</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container nonborderbox" style="background-color:lightblue;">    
    <div class="row" style="background-color:red;"> 
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange"><p style="background-color:green">Content</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange"><p style="background-color:green">Content</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With:

```
.nonborderbox *
{
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

The above will result in:

[image]

With `box-sizing: border-box` the gutter construct by padding will be out of the calculating of your column's width.

Try to understand Bootstrap's grid and the `box-sizing: border-box` and figure out why this will ruin your layout. Fix this problems or consider to don't use Bootstrap at all for your project.

Comment: I'm using CodeMirror. It goes crazy with `box-sizing: border-box`. Should I understand what's wrong in all the third party components I use, or is that a Bootstrap to blame?

Comment: I Have to agree with @polkovnikov.ph . I'm having the same issues with the DHTML scheduler library because Twitter is overriding the css generated by the scripts. If i turn off box-sizing everything displays as it should, with the calendar.

Comment: @TomT I've been interested in why `box-sizing` is set that way in Bootstrap. It's a "musthave" feature to make columns working. CodeMirror have added an explicit `box-sizing` since I wrote that comment. It seems the only viable fix is to make broken code `box-sizing`-agnostic.

Answer (score 60):

I have the same problem and bootstrap 3 destroys my existing layouts and third party widgets. Here are something things I've tried in order of increasing difficulty and stability.

## Easiest Way

*Safe only if you don't use other bootstrap components*

Add the following css after the bootstrap css is loaded:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}

.container .row *,
.container .row *:before,
.container .row *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will use the `border-box` sizing only for elements within the grid system. This won't work if you have custom widgets within the grid as they would still have `border-box` applied.

## More targeted approach

*Safe only if you don't use other bootstrap components*

Alternatively, you could add a custom `col` class to every column div which already have a `col-*-*` applied like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col">Grid still works</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col">:)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use the following css instead:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}

.container .row .col,
.container .row .col:before,
.container .row .col:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This works fine if you ONLY need to use the bootstrap grid system in your project. If you intend to use other bootstrap components however, I don't recommend this approach either since other bootstrap components would depend on the `border-box` being set.

## Cherry-pick each containing element to fix

A still better way would be to just override the box-sizing as `content-box` on a specific parent element for a widget like this:

```
.your-custom-widget-class *,
.your-custom-widget-class *:before,
.your-custom-widget-class *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

This approach offers the best forward compatibility with future bootstrap components, even if it seems to be working for you now.

Comment: I was having issues trying to use semantic-ui checkbox with bootstrap. Using user193130's last method did the trick. Awesome!!

Comment: Cherry pick option is ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your mixin or variables less and make sure it loads after scaffolding.less
It resets the bs3 box-sizing and applies it again to specific elements and all BS3 required elements. 
I found that most mess created by the default BS3 box sizing is when it is applied to

```
a,ul,li
```

The magic

```
* {
  .box-sizing(content-box);
}
form,
div,
img,
table,
th,
tr,
td,
p,
article, 
aside, 
details, 
figcaption, 
figure, 
footer, 
header, 
hgroup, 
main, 
nav, 
section, 
summary,
audio,
canvas,
progress,
video,
[class^="container-"], 
[class^="container-"] *,
[class^="col-"], 
[class^="col-"] *,
[class^="form-"],
[class^="form-"] *,
[class^="bg-"],
[class^="bg-"] *,
[class^="navbar"],
[class^="navbar"] *,
[class^="nav"],
[class^="nav"] *,
[class^="row"],
[class^="row"] * {
  .box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of above solutions to fit my need
(I used only the grid system, everything else was already there)

```
/* *,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*/


[class^="container-"], 
[class^="container-"] *,
[class^="col-"], 
[class^="col-"] *,
[class^="row"],
[class^="row"] * {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

The grid was taking too much margin and padding 
   so i replaced all the

```
padding-right:15px;
padding-left:15px;
margin-left=-15px;
margin-right=-15px;
```

to(I commented out the margins)

```
.row {
/*  margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;*/
}
```

and

```
.col, .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```