# Possible to make single div both a container and a row with Bootstrap mixins?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

In Bootstrap's grid system, the standard way to create a "row" is to use a markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       ... columns here ...
    </div>
</div>
```

In our project we use LESS and mixins and semantic classes so this would usually look like:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
       ...
    </div>
</div>

// LESS:
.content-wrapper {
    .container;
}

.content {
    .make-row();
}
```

However, those two DIVs are artificial, really, from the semantic point of view I only need one DIV. In Bootstrap, is there a way to somehow make it work with single containing DIV only? Obviously something like this doesn't work:

```
#content {
    // doesn't work
    .container;
    .make-row();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not explain, what is not working in your situation.

When you inspect the compiled CSS code, you will find:

```
#content {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

The above makes clear what happens. The `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties from your `.make-row()` (or even `.row`) mixins override the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties of the `.container` which center your grid.

When you understand why the  `.row` adds a negative margin you should consider if you do really need it. The negative margin play a role in [nesting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting). Because of the `.container` has a padding of 15 pixels on each side (and Bootstrap uses the [border-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box/18858771)) the .row (and columns) become smaller than the `.container` itself (the negative margin makes them the same width). When you nest a new row its width became 1 / x * (the width of the container - the padding of the container).

Depending of your needs, you can consider to skip the row and the padding of the `.container`:

```
#content {
    .container;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0; 
}
```

Possible related:

1. [Bootstrap 3 Gutter Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041733/bootstrap-3-gutter-size/19044326)
2. [How to change gutter widths on Responsable CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341817/how-to-change-gutter-widths-on-responsable-css-grid/26320184)