# Border not showing due to wildcard

Tags: css, border, wildcard

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2msz53n9/

And here is the problem:

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden
}
```

I need to use this for the rest of my site. So I cannot remove it. However, on my fiddle, I want the border to show also on the right, but now because of the above, it doesn't. I would like to have a solution where I can keep the above code, however, if not, I will have to review my whole site and re-do the CSS, I guess. I haven't been able to get the border on the right without removing that wildcard code though. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual width of `.rightcont` is 328px including 1px border on left and right.

So either increase `width` of `.right` to 328

Or add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.rightcont`

Comment: I seriously checked and tested that before and I didn't get it to work. Now, it works with the width change though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your list of wildcard rules:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2msz53n9/1/)**

Bootstrap actually does this and you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box).