# Creating a circle using `border-radius`

Tags: html, css

I am reading *HTML and CSS* by Jon Duckett, and have been introduced to the `border-radius` property.

I am trying to create a circle using the code below, but the circle is not perfect. I am using the radius of `50px` but it isn't perfect.

```css
p {
  border: 5px solid #ee3e80;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

p.three {
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="three"></p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not use vendor preixes for `border-radius` property because they are for very old browser (Firefox 4-, Chrome 4-, Safari 5-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`padding` and the width of the `border` is calculated additionally to the `width` and `height` of your element.

You have different options to solve this:

1. add `box-sizing: border-box` to your element which defines what should include in the size calculation
2. use `border-radius: 50%`
3. add your border-width and padding to your `border-radius`.

Here the solution just with `box-sizing`

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;

  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  /* these values get added to your 100px by default */
  border: 5px solid #ee3e80;
  padding: 10px;
}

p.three {
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  
  /* now width and height determine how big your
     element is as a whole */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p class="three"></p>
```

For a more detailed explanation about the CSS box model look at [this article from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model).

Answer (score 3):

It should be `50%`, not `50px`. `50%` will always draw a circle regardless of the size of the element. Setting a pixel value will only draw a circle if the element is sufficiently small.

See below.

```css
p {
  border: 5px solid #ee3e80;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

p.three {
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="three"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you didn't take into account the width coming from the border width, which is `5px` on each end. So the total width is `110px`, so your border radius will need to be `55px`. An easier way for a perfect circle is to just set `border-radius` to `50%`.

```css
p {
  border: 5px solid #ee3e80;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

p.three {
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="three"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `50%` to the `border-radius` property. Below is a snippet and you will find it is a perfect circle.

```css
p {
  border: 5px solid #ee3e80;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

p.three {
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="three"></p>
```

Comment: There's no reason a pixel value shouldn't work. This doesn't explain the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to set your element's `box-sizing` property to `border-box` (as I do for nearly all elements).

```css
p {
  border: 5px solid #ee3e80;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* < -------------------- here */ 
}

p.three {
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="three"></p>
```

`Border-box` takes into consideration border when doing math, and generally simplifies layout and styling when applied across the board. Libraries like Bootstrap [do this for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box).